Java 17 on older Android devices
We upgraded gradle in AS to 8.4.
Now AS insists we have to build with Java 17.
Will the apps still work on older devices that don't support Java 17 - as long as we don't use any new features above Java 11?
This is what I set in gradle:
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    java {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjvm-default=all']
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }


There's no "Android 17" (yet). And the Java version only has very lose connection to the Java version. For Android the important value is the minSdk that you configure. Then depending on the specific tooling version you use you may or may not be able to use newer Java features, but that depends on the Android gradle plugin and not on the Java VM version you're running on.

I meant Java 17. :face_palm:

no .
the only thing that specific the minmum sdk version is minSdk attribute in gradle module file
(you can locate it in ProjectDir/app/build.gradle.kts) :

android {
  //..

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 27 //8.1
        //..
    }
}

and there is no android 17 android version

My bad. I meant Java 17! Duh. Fixed it.
